# How Create a Class and Property dynamically from database table

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm

I need to Create a Class and Property dynamically from database table (Employee).
 [image]

I need to Create a class and property at runtime and assign value to property

for example

```css
public class Employee
{
    private int _Id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }

    private String _Code;

    public String Code
    {
        get { return _Code; }
        set { _Code = value; }
    }
}
```

Then I need to access this class on object

```
List<Employee> objlstEmp = new List<Employee>();
Employee objEmp = new Employee();
objEmp.Id = 1;
objEmp.Code = "Emp01";
objlstEmp.Add(objEmp);
```

Comment: Why cannot you use entity framework?

Comment: You need to read more about [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

Answer (score 0):

As others commented, from your example looks like you don't need to generate classes at runtime, but use an ORM framework and do that design time.

As it seems the topic is unfamiliar to you, I would recommend looking into [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) and because you already have a DB, generate the model from that. Look up how to [create the model from DB](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/using-entity-framework-with-an-existing-database-data-access/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your class is defined in your asembly and class property names are equal to field names in table. This would help...

```
    public static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row) where T : new()
    {
        // create a new object
        T item = new T();

        // set the item
        SetItemFromRow(item, row);

        // return 
        return item;
    }
    public static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row) where T : new()
    {
        // go through each column
        foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
        {
            try
            {
                // find the property for the column
                PropertyInfo p = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName);

                // if exists, set the value
                if (p != null && row[c] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    p.SetValue(item, row[c], null);
                }
                else if (p != null && row[c] == DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                    {
                        p.SetValue(item, DateTime.MinValue, null);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex; //catch what you wish
            }
        }
    }
```